# Division after groupby and conditional in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` and it has the columns `Numeric Rating`, `Current Balance` and `New Maturities`. I want to groupby `New Maturities` and then find the sum of `Current Balance` associated with a `Numeric Rating > 0.2` divided by the sum of `Current Balance` after just the groupby. I do it in the following way by using two dataframes and dividing the corresponding values and putting it into a `dict d`, but I was wondering if there might be a better way:

```
df_rat = df[df['Numeric Rating'] > 0.2]
W=df_rat.groupby(['New Maturities']).agg({'Current Balance':'sum'}).reset_index() 
W_=df.groupby(['New Maturities']).agg({'Current Balance':'sum'}).reset_index()
d = {}
for i in list(W['New Maturities']):
    d[str(i)] = W[W['New Maturities'] == i]['Current Balance'].values/W_[W_['New Maturities'] == i]['Current Balance'].values
```

`df` looks like follows and has 378 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''New Maturities,Current Balance,Numeric Rating
          7,3400000,0.075
          7,1945904,0.200
          5,2000000,0.300
          5,118812,0.400
          5,79208,0.300'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = ',', header = 0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve this method would be to eliminate the for loop altogether.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''New Maturities,Current Balance,Numeric Rating
          7,3400000,0.075
          7,1945904,0.200
          5,2000000,0.300
          5,118812,0.400
          5,79208,0.300'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = ',', header = 0)

df_rat = df[df['Numeric Rating'] > 0.2]

W=df_rat.groupby(['New Maturities']).agg({'Current Balance':'sum'}) 
W_=df.groupby(['New Maturities']).agg({'Current Balance':'sum'})

d=W_/W
```

`d` is a series and you could get your `d` with `d.to_dict`

All I've done is remove the `reset_index` so these `W` will remain series and we can allow pandas.Series.**div** to work with the index we want and then used the division.

As an aside, and only mildly related are custom agg functions. I say only mildly related because I could not think of a way to make use of them for your scenario and your method was already very direct. In case it might spark some other idea, here is the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html). An agg function will only take a single series at a time unfortunately.